# Is there a Gradle task to download testRuntime dependencies?

Tags: gradle

Is there a command that will instruct Gradle to resolve and download all `testRuntime` dependencies, but not run the tests?

Preferably, I want to do this without writing a custom task (such that the command can be run against *any* Gradle project).

For example, if my `build.gradle` has this dependency:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
}
```

The JAR files associated with `selenium-htmlunit-driver` are not downloaded until I run `gradle test`, which also runs the tests. I can download all other dependencies by running `gradle testClasses`, but not the `testRuntime` deps.

Comment: just run `gradle test` ?

Comment: potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814652 . Note there is a comment from 2014 that there is no way to download dependencies upfront.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the following in a file called `resolve.gradle`

```
gradle.allprojects { project ->
    project.task('resolveTestRuntime') {
        doLast {
            project.configurations.testRuntime.resolve()
        }
    }
}
```

Then run `resolve.gradle` as an [init script](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html)

```
gradlew --init-script resolve.gradle resolveTestRuntime
```

Comment: I don't think that's a valid init script. it seems `task` is not allowed. am i wrong?

Comment: correct... init scripts are have a [Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/invocation/Gradle.html) instance in scope whereas build.gradle has a [Project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html) in scope.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the answer from [Lance Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41459470/63308) into a valid Init script, I was able to accomplish this with the following `resolve.gradle`:

```
apply plugin:MyInitPlugin

class MyInitPlugin implements Plugin<Gradle> {
  @Override
  void apply(Gradle gradle) {
    gradle.allprojects{ project ->
      project.task('resolveTestRuntime') {
        doLast {
          project.configurations.testRuntime.resolve()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then running:

```
gradlew --init-script resolve.gradle resolveTestRuntime
```

Comment: You don't need a plugin... you can just use the `gradle.allprojects { ... }` snippet

Comment: Thanks. If you want to edit your answer with this, I'll accept it.