# How to make gradle download dependencies without actually building things

Tags: java, gradle

On a new environment `gradle build` takes quite a while because all dependencies have to be downloaded.

Is there a way to only download dependencies in order to speed up the following build?

That way we could for example already prefill a CI build environment.

Comment: dependencies are locally cached after the first build, so the second build will be faster

Comment: Exactly. But I want to have the local cache without actually building things.

Comment: not sure what you want to accomplish. The time spent would be the same one way or the other.
If you have multiple build machines, you could look into using a proxy to manage dependencies (like Artifactory).

Otherwise, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814652/how-to-download-dependencies-in-gradle

Comment: Also note that if you are using gradle 4+ you should use the --parallel flag, this will greatly speed up pulling of dependencies.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer in order to have a "dependencies" docker cache layer equivalent to `npm install`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Edit: Updated for Gradle 6+.

Some notes:

- This new approach downloads jars into a folder, and then deletes the folder. So the result of having the jars in the Gradle cache is a side-effect.
- It currently uses jars configured for the `main` source-set but could be generalized.
- Even though it is neither efficient nor elegant, it can be useful if you actually want the jars (and transitive dependencies): simply comment-out the deletion of the `runtime` folder.

This solution can be handy when you *want* the jars (and transitive dependencies), as you simply have to comment-out deleting the folder.

Consider this `build.gradle` (as an arbitrary, concrete example):

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2'
    implementation 'org.kie.modules:org-apache-commons-lang3:6.2.0.Beta2'
}

repositories { 
   jcenter()
}

task getDeps(type: Copy) {
    from sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
    into 'runtime/'

    doFirst {
        ant.delete(dir: 'runtime')
        ant.mkdir(dir: 'runtime')
    }

    doLast {
        ant.delete(dir: 'runtime')
    }
}
```

Example run:

```
$ find /Users/measter/.gradle/caches -name "commons-io*1.3.2.jar"

$ gradle getDeps

$ find /Users/measter/.gradle/caches -name "commons-io*1.3.2.jar"
/Users/measter/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/commons-io/commons-io/1.3.2/[snip]/commons-io-1.3.2.jar
```

Comment: It seems to download only the meta information (pom) but not the actual jar file (tested with Gradle 6).

Comment: I have revised the approach and tested with Gradle 6.2. It is not elegant but it does populate the Gradle cache with the specified jars.

Comment: I am able to use this approach under Gradle 5.6.4. I also added `from sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath` in addition to sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath and instead put it under the `build/` dir, so that a `clean` would remove it. here is my getDeps task.  
---

```language: gradle
task getDeps(type: Copy) {
  from sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
  from sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
  into 'build/deps'

  doFirst {
      ant.delete(dir: 'build/deps')
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution triggers compilation, not so convenient

Answer (score 11):

I've found `./gradlew dependencies` (as suggested by [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50219857/5352605)) to be very handy for Docker builds.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a custom task that resolves all the configurations( in doing so, it will also download the dependencies without building the project)

```
task downloadDependencies { 
   doLast { 
       configurations.findAll{it.canBeResolved}.each{it.resolve()}
   }
}
```

Run command ./gradlew downloadDependencies

Answer (score 0):

My answer will favor the gradle plugins and built-in tasks.

I would use "gradle assemble" in the command-line.

It is a minor version of "gradle build".

This way, you may reduce the time of your preparations before running or building anything.

Check the link bellow for the documentation:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#lifecycle_tasks

In general, what is my recipe when I clone a new repository:

-gradle assemble

-do some coding

-gradle run (and basically test until done)

-gradle build (to make distributable files)

note: this last step may have adicional configurations for .jar files as outputs (depends on you).