# gradle - task to only download maven dependencies

Tags: gradle

Is there a task in gradle that will simply download the dependencies from the maven repository?

The dependencies in my build.gradle file are specified as follows.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.8.0'
}
```

The only way I have been able to do this is to actually perform a build (e.g. ./gradlew build ), however that takes too much time if all I want to do retrieve the dependencies.

Comment: https://github.com/palantir/gradle-configuration-resolver-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned how to do it thanks to @louis-jacomet.

With a `build.gradle` file like this,

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}

configurations {
    scm
}

dependencies {
    scm "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5"
}

task lib(type: Copy) {
    into "/path/to/download"
    from configurations.scm
}
```

and start downloading by `gradle lib`. Surely you can use other task name than `lib`.

Answer (score 15):

You can run `./gradlew dependencies` which will print a [report about the dependencies of your build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/inspecting_dependencies.html), and to do so will have to resolve them.

Note however that the download happens only if Gradle does not have them in cache already.

Comment: You're a hacker bro, this works perfectly in Docker.