# Offline Android Gradle Plugin

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, plugins, offline

Please does anyone have idea of another site I can download the offline android gradle plugin from?
I previously downloaded it from the official developer.android site but they only have the beta version and not the plugin itself,it keeps giving me error plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found,I run Android 4.0 btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android Gradle Plugin is hosted at Google's Maven repository: https://maven.google.com/
You can craft `pom.xml` with the needed `com.android.tools.build:gradle` artifact and use `mvn dependency:resolve` to download both the plugin and all it's dependencies, including transitive ones.
Gradle doesn't support similar action out of the box, see [answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814652) for the ways to achieve the same task with Gradle.

I don't recall `id 'com.android.application'` working without any modifications via `pluginManagement { ... }` in `settings.gradle`, similar to the following:

```kotlin
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()

        mavenLocal() // one should add this for artifacts mirrored locally
    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.id.startsWith("com.android.")) {
                useModule("com.android.tools.build:gradle:${requested.version}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you use the same way, don't forget to add your local repository, be it `mavenLocal()` or anything else, to `pluginManagement { repositories { ... }}`.

For the general case unrelated to Android plugin (yet?):

A plugin called `com.example.myplugin` should have the corresponding artifact of `com.example.myplugin:com.example.myplugin.gradle.plugin:...` in Gradle plugins repository (https://plugins.gradle.org/m2). This artifact should also be mirrored locally for `id "com.example.myplugin"` to work.

For the reference, here's the full `pom.xml` that I've used to download all needed artifacts for AGP 4.0.0:

```
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.android.tools.build</groupId>
      <artifactId>gradle</artifactId>
      <version>3.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.61</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.61</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.61</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- addendum for 4.0.0 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.errorprone</groupId>
      <artifactId>error_prone_annotations</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>goog</id>
      <url>https://dl.google.com/android/maven2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>jcr</id>
      <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

After running `mvn dependency:resolve` artifacts would reside in `~/.m2/repository`, so all that's left is to add `mavenLocal()` to `pluginManagement { repositories { ... } }` (or `buildscript { repositories { ... } }` for old style of applying plugins).

Comment: i've downloaded the offline dependencies,the only problem is the offline plugin,they probably posted the wrong one because it says "plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found after you run it

Comment: Sure. See https://gist.github.com/r4zzz4k/064d286a5b4e2322475b3efae1cc69b0
`pom.xml` has the list of all dependencies I had to download. Then I ran `mvn dependency:resolve`. After that `gradle tasks` successfully gets the plugin (note there are no repositories apart from `mavenLocal()`), and AGP itself drops me `compileSdkVersion is not specified` due to unfinished configuration.

Comment: I've just updated that for 4.0.0, it needed an additional dependency.
Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you to solve the issue :)

Comment: Okay,after going through the issue over and over,I figured out the error has to do with my Build.app module source code, can you please send me your full build.app module source code so that I can check if I can configure it

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "Build.app module source code". Could you please clarify that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm away from my PC for the several days. It's just a usual build.gradle, based on the stuff I've posted in a Gist above, with added usual Android-related configuration. Nothing special. If that's not working for you, please provide additional details what you've done and what errors do you get.

Comment: okay,tbh i didn't follow your instructions at first but the moment i changed my settings.gradle code today to the one you posted above,it totally solved the issue.I'm very sorry for not doing it at first But thanks a lot bro,your quite a genius,just solved an issue i've been having for weeks!

Comment: @r4zzz4k  could you please refer https://stackoverflow.com/q/69821518/1665247. thanks