# Offline gradle plugin not found in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I need help, I am quite new to Android Studio and I want to build all my projects fully offline due to internet connection issues during the day. According to Google's own [Android Developer website](https://developer.android.com/studio) this should be possible. I have all the files they said are required, I have the JDK, the Google Maven dependencies and the Android Gradle Plugin fully downloaded and unzipped from the official site. But when I try to build I get this error.

```
5:08:20 PM: Executing task 'build'...

Executing tasks: [build] in project /home/vukona/AndroidStudioProjects/FirstAndroidProject


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'First Android Project'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/home/vukona/.android/manual-offline-m2/android-gradle-plugin-3.5.0-beta01/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom
       - file:/home/vukona/.android/manual-offline-m2/gmaven_stable/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.0.1/gradle-4.0.1.pom
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 247ms
5:08:21 PM: Task execution finished 'build'.
```

From this what I understand is that the specific version of the gradle plugin Google makes us download is not the current gradle plugin Android Studio is looking for. But I don't know how to add the more recent version, even though there is a lot of posts regarding this, they don't specify the files where we should be inserting some of the scripts they are giving us, and how to even execute those scripts. I am a beginner when it comes to the whole Android Studio development environment, so please be patient and specific with your answers. So far these are the answers I ran into: [how to download gradle dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814652/how-to-download-dependencies-in-gradle/44168582#44168582), but I'm not sure where this is supposed to be and [how to include gradle dependencies using settings.gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63569938/offline-android-gradle-plugin), but again I have no idea what is really happening here either. So if anyone can be so kind, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just get decent internet somehow and do these steps:

1. Reopen the Android Studio. once again, make sure you're online.
2. Click File -> Sync project with Gradle files. Wait until the process finished.
3. You can turn off your internet
4. Click Build -> Make Project. There will be an error appear in the bottom.
5. on Build Output, right bottom side, click: Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
6. You should be able to build the project just fine.

But remember, there are several things which can make this failed. one of them is if you use dynamic dependency inside your project. These steps will only work if all dependency is listed in your build.gradle files and no runtime dependencies.

Another discussion about this, you can read on Quora: https://www.quora.com/Can-I-use-Android-Studio-offline

Comment: Aren't all the dependencies supposed to be covered in the Google Maven dependencies zip provided in the [Android Developer website](https://developer.android.com/studio) so that we can point Android Studio to the local files instead of an online server?

Comment: no, they don't. you can't expect all dependencies would be there. the size will be too big you yourself won't be able to download them all. believe me, I knew someone who tried to download all the dependencies which android studio need, it takes more than 100GB

Comment: 100GB without external libraries? Just maven? Because right now I can't even build new basic projects without  any user added dependencies.

Comment: you are new to android studio, right? that's android studio for you. even a new project depends on non-existent gradle version by default. so you at least need to sync the gradle once before you can create new project. just follow my steps. at least I know it will work.

Comment: if my answer help you, please tick / choose it as answer to this question

Comment: I understand everything you said, but my question is why is there an offline file if I can't even build a simple menu-only app with those downloaded files? To make matters worse, Android studio doesn't seem to make it easy to even connect its gradle to the offline repo.

Comment: android studio is not meant to be used offline. I can guarantee what I just said. So if you want to use it offline, you must do extra works. By default you can't use it offline and expect it to work 100% as you want. This is unwritten anywhere, but any android studio user who work with it at least 3 months will know this. by the way, why don't you just sync your gradle just only ONCE? it will work offline after that.